# Does Jupiter rotate at the same speed at every depth?

Tags: jupiter

Jupiter rotates in less than 10 hours. Its rotation is differential, with the upper layers of the atmosphere spinning a bit faster at the equator than at higher latitudes. Do the inner layers of Jupiter rotate at the same (angular) speed as the outmost layers of the atmosphere?

Comment: Well, if the inner layers have the same angular speed then they have a lower linear speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The deep interior of the planet rotates as (nearly) a rigid body ([Guillot et al. 2018](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature25775)), while the outer part of the planet undergoes differential rotation. Therefore the interior and exterior rotation cannot match at all latitudes simultaneously.

Comment: Quite a cool paper! I think this was about the time that single, well characterized value for the rotational period of Jupiter could be ascertained?